# How to compare two rows or get the fields which value is not match with the rows that compared?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, compare

I'm trying to get the fields which value is not match base on the compared rows. It's hard to explain so I'll put the sample table and its results.

**Table:** orders

```
|  seqid  |  orderId  |  taskId  |  field1  |  field2  |  field3  |  field4  |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+ 
|  1      |  1        |  1       |  a       |  b       |  c       |  d       |
|  2      |  1        |  2       |  a       |  b       |  c       |  d       |
|  3      |  2        |  1       |  a       |  b       |  c       |  d       |
|  4      |  2        |  2       |  a       |  c       |  c       |  c       |
|  5      |  3        |  1       |  a       |  a       |  a       |  a       |
```

**Results:**

```
|  OrderId  |  FieldName  |  Error  |
+-----------+-------------+---------+
|  2        |  field2     |  1      |
|  2        |  field4     |  1      |
```

Here you can see that the `orderId` will be compared using its `taskId`. From field1 to field4 are the fields to be check if their values are not match. If so, then get the field name. The column `Error` is not a priority, you can disregard it. If the orderId has only one task then it will not be compared.

My first plan is to use two query that will separate the `taskId` then Java will do the rest. But if possible with just a query that would be great. Even though I'm not knowledgeable with stored procedure, if its the only way then let me show and I'll check on it.

I don't have any working query yet or even get a result as close to what I wanted. Any answer will be appreciate. Thanks!

**UPDATED:**

I guess the results is difficult to answer. I'll post another result which is I think much easy to solve.

**Results2**

```
|  orderId  |  field1  | field2  | field3  |  field4  |
+-----------+----------+---------+---------+----------+
|  1        |  0       | 0       | 0       |  0       |
|  2        |  0       | 1       | 0       |  1       |
```

For the second results I need to know if the field has unmatched value if yes it will display 1. The process of this results is to compare the two rows which is the `Task = 1` and `Task = 2` with same `orderId`. I will filter the fields which have unmatched value in Java.

I hope someone here can answer it even the second results. If you can answer the first results, that would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  orderId,
  CASE MIN(field1) WHEN MAX(field1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS field1,
  CASE MIN(field2) WHEN MAX(field2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS field2,
  ...
FROM atable
GROUP BY
  orderId
```

Comment: Thanks this work base on my given data. But I guess I will have a problem joining this to my query, but I know it will not a problem for me. Although I already have a working query I'll try this later, to check which is more optimized. But I guess this is more optimized with my query. Well done, Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select orderid
from orders
group by orderid
having count(*) > 1
and min(field1) <> max(field1) and min(field2) <> max(field2) ...
```

Comment: I have tried it, but its not working as per my expected results. Thanks!